# Use awk to split one file into many files

Tags: awk, gawk

Have a Master file (Master.txt) where each row is a string defining an HTML page and each field is tab delimited.
The record layout is as follows:

```
<item_ID>   <field_1>   <field_2>   <field_3>
1   1.html  <html>[content for 1.html in HTML format]</html>    <EOF>
2   2.html  <html>[content for 2.html in HTML format]</html>    <EOF>
3   3.html  <html>[content for 3.html in HTML format]</html>    <EOF>
```

The HTML page is defined in `<field_2>`. `<field_3>` may not be necessary, but included here to indicate the logical location of end_of_file.

How to use `awk` to generate a file for each row (which begins with `<item_ID>`) where the content of the new file is `<field_2>` and the name of the new file is `<field_1>`?

Am running `GNUwin32` under `Windows 7` and will configure an `awk` solution to execute in a `.bat` file. Unfortunately can't do pipe-lining in Windows, so hoping for an single-awk-program solution.

TY in advance.

Comment: Something like `awk -F"\t" '{print $3 > $2}' file` should make it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the first field in AWK as file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555588/using-the-first-field-in-awk-as-file-name)

Comment: Can `[content for 1.html in HTML format]`, etc. contain tab characters or not?

Comment: @fedorqui that would be an answer!

Comment: @Ed the only use of tabs is as a delimiter. Specifically, no tab in <field_2> (the field with HTML content.

Comment: @fedorqui Sorry - completely missed that solution when searching stackoverflow. Also - FYI - it did not pop when options are offered after entering the title.

Comment: Jay if there's guaranted no tabs in the html then @fedorqui's suggestion would work fine if you add a `NR>1` to the front of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the HTML in `field 3` may or may not contain tabs:

```
awk -F'\t' 'match($0,/<html>.*<\/html>/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) > $2}' file
```

Comment: @Kent yes, it is $2 (the field with the target file name)

Comment: @Ed I now have several Ed_Morton_files in my library.

Comment: @Kent & Jay, thanks I updated the solution now to print to $2. If there's guaranteed to be no tabs in the HTML though then fedorqui's solution in a comment would work just as well if you add a `NR>1` to the front of it.